# Can 气候 literally or non-literally mean "atmosphere"?

Tags: meaning, word

> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%B0%94%E5%80%99): 气候 (qì​hòu​) climate / atmosphere / situation / CL: 種｜种

I'm puzzled as to why "atmosphere" is listed here.  Literally, an atmosphere is a gaseous layer that surrounds a planet, usually corresponding to 大气 in Chinese.  I don't think 气候 can literally mean "atmosphere".  Perhaps 气候 can mean "atmosphere" in a non-literal sense (e.g., "a tense atmosphere"), but I'd use 气氛 here.

**Question**: Can 气候 literally or non-literally mean "atmosphere"?

I asked [ChatGLM](https://chatglm.cn) for an example where 气候 means "atmosphere", but it gave me examples where it means "climate".

Comment: I think you are correct.

Comment: I sent the CC-CEDICT editor(s) a link to this post, and they changed the definition to:  `(meteorology) climate / (fig.) climate; prevailing conditions (in human affairs) / CL: 種｜种`.

Comment: Glad to know. Good work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atmosphere is not just the aerosol we live and breath in. Figuratively, atmosphere and climate mean "mood".

"There was an icy atmosphere in the room."

I think some writers have taken this English meaning and used the Chinese word in that sense. Maybe they should use 气氛 or 局势。

> Atmosphere: the pervading tone or mood of a place, situation, or work
> of art:
>
> "the hotel is famous for its friendly, welcoming atmosphere" ·
>
> "this crisis further compounded the prevailing atmosphere of gloom"

气候：（局势） climate; situation:
political climate/atmosphere;
政治气候
a climate/atmosphere of political unrest
动荡的政治气候

当时的宗教气候（局势）容不得新思想。

Answer (score 1):

> Question: Can 气候 literally or non-literally mean "atmosphere"?

气候 cannot be translated as "atmosphere" literally or non-literally

"Atmosphere" can figuratively mean 气氛 or 氛围 (mainland Chinese)
. Maybe ChatGLM confused 气候 with 气氛

the non-literal meaning of 气候 is "influence" as in 不成气候 (no influence; not a factor)

Answer (score 1):

> Question: Can 气候 literally or non-literally mean "atmosphere"?

Answer is no.

We usually say **气候问题**(such as temperature raise) in English is **climate issue**

See below picture:

[image]

atmosphere in Chinese usually means: 大气；空气；大气圈

Such as:

```
The burning of fossil fuels results in the pollution of the atmosphere.
矿物燃料的燃烧导致了大气污染。

The atmosphere of the city is very much polluted.
那个城市的空气受到严重污染。
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be used for a figurative climate/situation in cantonese alongside its literal climate meaning, although I don't believe its really used that way in standard chinese.

While I don't believe atmosphere ever actually applies to the meaning of this word, I can think of nonliteral climate/situations that could be described with atmosphere in english.  I believe this is where the definition is coming from.